# Json response parsing is not working after upgrading xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

Check Below Error,

[image]

I have upgrade my xcode 7.3 to xcode 8.1 before up gradation my code is working fine but after upgrading xcode it will give above error please help me. Thank you

Comment: You need to explicitly specify type of `JSON` to `Dictionary` like,  `if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any]`

Comment: Thank you.it will works for me..